# How do I multisort data that is in the future in descending order, then data in the past in ascending order?

Tags: mysql, sorting

Here is the mysql query:

```
SELECT `listings`.*
FROM `listings`
WHERE `listings`.`site_id` = '2'
  AND `listings`.`type_id` = '2'
GROUP BY `listings`.`book_id`
ORDER BY
  (CASE WHEN DATE(`listings`.`extended_end_datetime`) < DATE(CURDATE()) 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) ASC,
  `listings`.`extended_end_datetime` DESC ,
  `listings`.`dates_tentative` asc;
```

Here is how it currently sorts:

[image: Wrong sorting]

Here is how I would like it to sort:

[image: Correct sorting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample data this will work:

```
order by 
  extended_end_datetime < curdate(),
  abs(timestampdiff(minute, extended_end_datetime, now())) ,
  dates_tentative
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hUHz3f8qXXs1mZHzh3YGKF/0).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `listings`.* 
FROM `listings` 
WHERE `listings`.`site_id` = '2' AND `listings`.`type_id` = '2' 
GROUP BY `listings`.`book_id` 
ORDER BY 
 (CASE WHEN DATE(`listings`.`extended_end_datetime`) < DATE(CURDATE()) THEN -1 ELSE 1 END) *
     TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, DATE(`listings`.`extended_end_datetime`), DATE(CURDATE()),
 `listings`.`extended_end_datetime` DESC , 
 `listings`.`dates_tentative` asc
```

It calculate the time difference between today, and the date in the DB, and multiplies it with 1 or -1 depending on how you want to sort.